# Problem with grub 2 to launch Win 10 - /bootmgr missing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I installed the new 20.04 LTS Ubuntu desktop, close to Win 10. When I ran the installer, it saw the win 10 boot files, but I don't know why: it failed before the end. So I restarted, and could not see the win 10 bott files anymore.

So I can boot on my new ubuntu, but no more on the Win 10, so I added manually in 40_custom grub config file; and I have the error /bootmgr missing. I tried to use win tools to rebuild it but nothing change. With gparted I added the boot flag on my sda2, but my problem is continuing...
I don't know what to do to fix it

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MvfNrJmYn5/

THANK YOU

Comment: What is or was sda1? Drive is now shown as gpt and Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt. But with gpt Windows has a lot of partitions. It looks more like a BIOS/MBR install of Windows with sda1 as primary NTFS boot partition & sda2 as install. But converting to gpt would break a Windows BIOS install. I might try repairs on sda1, but Window repair disk may not repair it? You cannot do most Windows repairs from Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)